# Connection to NEAR Wallet following documentation does not work

Tags: nearprotocol

I started checking out the NEAR protocol following [near quick reference](https://docs.near.org/docs/api/naj-quick-reference#connection)

But I get the error "Property 'keyStores' does not exist on type 'typeof import("../near-api-js/lib/index")'." on this line

```
const { connect, keyStores, WalletConnection } = nearAPI;
```

Answer (score 0):

Adding the TS ignore declariation makes it compile:

```
// @ts-ignore
const { connect, keyStores, KeyPair } = nearAPI;
```